# how to set X axis as dates from my SQL extraction temporary file?

Tags: gnuplot

After many reading something is not working in my use-case
and I do not really understand why for the moment.

My extract looks like that :

```
 111 | 98.2 | 2020-07-11
 112 | 99.2 | 2020-07-15
 113 | 98.7 | 2020-07-25
 122 | 99.2 | 2020-07-26
 123 | 99.7 | 2020-07-27
 124 | 97.8 | 2020-07-28
```

& my gnuplot code looks like :

```
gnuplot --persist << EOF || ( exit 3 ) 
set xlabel "temps"
set ylabel "poid"
set terminal GNUTERM background rgb 'grey' size 1024,768
set grid ls 12
set sample 1000
set datafile separator "|"
set yrange [95:100]
set title "SUIVI POID"
set autoscale
plot "poid" with lines smooth bezier , "regime" with lines lt rgb "red" , "objectif" with lines smooth bezier lt rgb "white"
set terminal png
set output 'poid.png'
replot
pause mouse close
EOF
```

Doing so I have my curves & weight etc...
**But I have my 111 , 112 , ... , 124  values as X labels**

I tried to  replace by date : like that *(adding few lines of sets)* :

```
set autoscale
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m"
set format x "%b %d"
set xrange ["04/07":"31/12"]
set xtics "04/07",172800,"31/12"
plot "poid" with lines smooth bezier , "regime" with lines lt rgb "red" , "objectif" with lines smooth bezier lt rgb "white"
set terminal png
```

and got that error :

```
gnuplot> plot "poid" with lines smooth bezier , "regime" with lines lt rgb "red" , "objectif" with lines smooth bezier lt rgb "white"
                                              ^
         line 0: Need full using spec for x time data
```

I tried many thing around that issue but I failed . I read many forums solutions but noone seem to match with my issue *(and I misunderstand some solutions also)*

**I want the dates as X labels**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where very close, the main issue is that you are not declaring the date format correctly, `timefmt` should represent the format of the dates in the data, you can set the `xrange` using the same format, then you can plot with `using 3:2` to tell gnuplot to use the column 3 for the x coordinates, and the column 2 for the y coordinates.

Making this adjustment to your script

```
set xlabel "temps"
set ylabel "poid"
set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'grey' fillstyle solid noborder
set grid ls 12
set sample 1000
set datafile separator "|"
set yrange [95:100]
set title "SUIVI POID"
set autoscale
set autoscale
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%b %d"
set xrange ['2020-07-11':'2020-07-28']
plot "test.txt" u 3:2  with lines smooth bezier
```

I got this plot from the sample data extract you posted.
[image: plot]

PD. The `qt` terminal doesn't have a background property, so I used a rectangle behind everything instead.